# jQuery looping through open dialogs to get/update position of each

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, positioning

I am trying to make the jQuery dialogs stay in their position relative to the window size, so for instance:

- If the original viewport width is 900px and there are 2 dialogs, one at 100,100 and another at 450,200
- When the window is resized to say 1200px, the first dialog would be 400,100 and the second at 750,200

I currently have this code handling the window resize, but it doesn't update the dialog positions:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    widthCompensation = getBrowserWidths();
    jQuery(".dialog-class").each(function() {
        var myPosition = jQuery(this).dialog("option", "position");
        var newLeft = parseInt(myPosition.context.offsetLeft+widthCompensation);
        var newTop = parseInt(myPosition.context.offsetTop);
        jQuery(this).dialog("option", "position", [newLeft,newTop]);
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Modified code:

```
function getBrowserWidths() {
    var standardWidth = 990;
    var actualWidth = parseInt(jQuery(window).width());
    var ret = (actualWidth-standardWidth)/ 2;
    return(ret);
}
var leftPositions = new Array();
var widthCompensation = getBrowserWidths();

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    widthCompensation = getBrowserWidths();
    jQuery(".target-class").each(function(i) {
        var newLeft = leftPositions[i]+widthCompensation; 
        console.log(newLeft);
        jQuery(this).css({"left": newLeft+"px"});
    });
});

//loop through draggables to get their initial positions
jQuery(".target-class").each(function(i) {
    var myPosition = jQuery(this).offset();
    leftPositions[i] = myPosition.left;
});
```

Comment: Hi, the getBrowserWidths function works? Is it possible to have its code? And just one thing to avoid the code not to execute on IE, use

var widthCompensation = ...  without var, IE is lost ^^ (not the only situation it is though...)

Comment: The getBrowserWidths function works fine. The code is:
function getBrowserWidths() {
 var standardWidth = 990;
 var actualWidth = parseInt(jQuery(window).width());
 var ret = (actualWidth-standardWidth)/ 2;
 return(ret);
}

I have defined the widthCompensation variable earlier in the script and need access to this once it has been updated outside of the function scope, hence not using var within the function. This might be wrong though I'm not that up to speed on JavaScript variable scopes.

Comment: Just wondering, the problem is not myPosition.context.offsetLeft ?

Why not use myPosition.left and myPosition.top? (not sure, but this seemed more logical to me)

Comment: because for some reason the only way I can access the object is by going through context.
myPosition.left and .top return NaN values

This is the top level properties of the object as seen by console.log() in Chrome (as Firebug's console is getting on my nerves at the moment breaking on errors throughout the jQuery core, console not working properly etc etc) 

Object
0: HTMLDivElement
context: HTMLDivElement
length: 1
__proto__: Object

All the normal properties of the dialog seem to be within context

Answer (score 0):

Using this in the each, it quite worked for me (if the dialog doesn't reach the corner of the browser.

```
var myPosition = $(this).offset();
var newLeft = myPosition.left+widthCompensation; 
var newTop = myPosition.top;    
$(this).dialog("option", "position", [newLeft,newTop]);
```

Hope it helps ;)

For the each, you can use the Index (here i),

```
var newLeft = new Array();
var newTop = new Array();
$(".dialog-class").each(function(i) {
  var myPosition = $(this).offset();
  var newLeft[i] = myPosition.left+widthCompensation; 
  var newTop[i] = myPosition.top;   
  $(this).dialog("option", "position", [newLeft[i],newTop[i]]);
});
```

Didn't test it so not 100% sure, but here is the idea.

Comment: thanks, using that as a basis I have managed to get the positions to update on resize although I need to store their original position somewhere as this ends up with exponential incrementation of the left and top positions (as it's always adding the offset to it's current position, need to add the offset to the individual dialog start positions). Is there any way to assign a variable to each instance?

Comment: There is a crappy way I'm thinking of, don't know if there is neater one, I guess so, but I'm not a specialist. I'm editing my answer ;)

Comment: Sorry I got some urgent jobs to do so didn't have chance to take a look. I think this is almost what I'm looking for, but wouldn't it still cause the same exponential issue as it's updating the array every time? I need to be able to handle adding extra dialogs into the page and I can't guarantee that if I add to the array when a new dialog is created that jQuery will loop through them in the correct order. Each dialog has a unique ID that I could reference if that helps? Or could I assign the variable to each individual object?

Comment: If that's your question on a simple selector like a class, the order of the elements in the each will match the order in which they appear in the DOM. The order matters for the process? Because here, it calculates the position of each element at each resize, maybe this is not really optimized, but I don't see how to improve this. Btw, the initialization of arrays, would better be performed outside the resize function to avoid useless assignments.

Comment: What I have done is used a separate each to loop through all the existing dialogs on page load and record their positions, the window resize function now calculates the widthCompensation on each resize call and then iterates through the each(), gets it's starting position and adds the compensation to it. I can get this newLeft position to display in the console & seems to be calculating the correct value, but I'm updating the left position via CSS (they're actually draggables not dialogs - that's my mistake) & it only seems to happen on the first call of the function. I'll update my question